# Azure Logic Apps: Read XML from file and Write a JSON with data

Tags: json, xml, api, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm new in it and trying to understand Azure Logic Apps.
I would like to create a LogicApp that:

Looks for new XML-Files

and for each file:

Read the XML

Check if Node "attachment" is present

and for each Attachment:

Read the Filename

Get the File from FTP and do BASE64-encoding

End for each Attachment.

Write JSON File (I have a schema)

DO HTTP-Post to API with JSON file as "application/json"

Is this possible with the Logic-Apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

- Check if a node is present, with **xpath expression** (e.g. xpath(xml(item()),'string(//Part/@ref)'))
- For Get File from FTP, use the action **FTP - Get File Content**
- Write JSON File, use the action **Data Operations - Compose**. If you need transformations, you have to use an Integration Account and Maps.
- Do HTTP Post to API, use de action **HTTP**

Comment: What abou the Base64encoding of files (pdf, jpg, zip)? Is that possible?

Comment: You can handle it and within the code you have several functions: base64 Return the base64-encoded version for a string., base64ToBinary Return the binary version for a base64-encoded string, base64ToString Return the string version for a base64-encoded string, ...

Comment: what i need is: Read from XML Node the Filename, look in ftp storage for the file and encode to base64

Comment: Correct! That's it ... you read the XML Node with xpath, use the FTP - Get File Content to get the file content and transform to Base64 if you need, but I think that FTP connector returns the file in base64, if no, you can encode it with the code functions ... all within the Logic App.